# Database User Password from SSIS/SQL Agent

Tags: ssis, sql-agent, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS package that I'm trying to run from a SQL job. However, it fails, and the log claims that the password for the user specified in the connection string is wrong. For testing I've got the protection level set to EncryptSensitiveWithKey, and it runs fine from BIDS. When I import it into SSIS I change it to ServerStorage. (My understanding of the documentation says that this should work. I could be wrong though.) During the import it asks for the decryption key, which I supply, and everything seems fine.

It also seems fine when I set up the job in SQL Server Agent. However, when I run the job, it fails and the log says that the password for that user is incorrect. It doesn't say that there is a permission problem, but that the password is wrong.

I've been through the connections and double checked the username and password that is used to access the database. I can connect just fine with that username and password combination. This is the user that is used to connect to the database. There don't appear to be any problems executing the job.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, it seems like you still need to modify the password after you have installed it to the SQL Agent.  The decryption key decrypts the sensitive information but it is still tied to the person that created it. Have you tried re-entering the password when you install it to the server?

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/

Comment: Yes, I entered the password on the server. I even did EncryptAllWithPassword in the hopes that if it was a problem with decrypting the package there would be an error. It decrypts it just fine, it's just that the password for my database user is either disappearing or not working.

Comment: The article I posted suggests that even though you decrypted the package, the actual connection string password may be lost because you are logged on as a different Windows user.

Comment: I just set the packages to not save sensitive, and created a configuration file, which I then edited so that the connection string included the password, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Is there any IP restrictions on the username?  Can you log on from the SQL agent's PC to access this data?  (long-shot I know but this problem is a tough one)

Comment: I'm currently using SQL based security, and I can create a connection from BIDS or Visual Studio using the same username and password that I've specified in the package.

Comment: I also just tried putting the password into the final package file and loading that into the job step from the filesystem. That didn't work either.

Comment: This didn't end up solving my immediate problem, but I followed the steps in the link when I started from scratch and rebuilt the package. It seems to be working now.